# directive for reactive form validation not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement required field validation using directive and its not working. I need to apply the class to highlight the box red based on validation run. At the moment it looks like the requirefieldvalidator is not getting triggered. Not sure what is wrong here. Is it fine using it in the ngClass like the way I have done.

This is what I have tried

```
  <label>Phone number</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" formControlName="phoneNo"  [ngClass]="{'isError' : 'requiredFieldValidator  [submitted] = submitted'}" />
</div>
```

Directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[requiredFieldValidator]',
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: RequiredFieldValidatorDirective , multi: true}]
})
export class RequiredFieldValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input() submitted: boolean = false;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        return (this.submitted || control.touched) && control.errors?.required;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the first question is why you are writing a directive? You can add a custom validator. Reference : https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: I can see the link that you shared is using a directive as well

Comment: Basically what I am trying to achieve is that I want to eliminate adding the following check to each and every form control (this.submitted || control.touched) && control.errors?.required. I need to also appy css style based on the out come

Comment: In that case, you can create a shared service and pass the necessary parameters and return to [ngClass] value to apply class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add directives like that inside ngClass, `[ngClass]` expects possible variables, not directives. If you want to add a directive that does styles, I would use hostbinding instead and inject the formcontrol in the directive to check it's validity and apply class when needed.

So template would be:

```html
<input
  formControlName="phoneNo"
  validityStyle 
  [submitted]="submitted"
/>
```

`validityStyle` being our directive here.

As mentioned, we inject the formontrol into the directive, also take your `submitted` variable and use `HostBinding` to add  your `isError` class to the input field when wanted:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[validityStyle]',
})
export class ValidityStyleDirective {
  @Input() submitted: boolean;
  constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  @HostBinding('class.isError')
  get myClass() {
    return (this.submitted || this.ngControl.touched) && !this.ngControl.valid
  }
}
```

Here's a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uqlra-4msuxv?file=src%2Fmain.ts)** for your reference

Comment: I have tried to add the directive as you suggested. I am however getting error saying cant find property submitted since its not a known property to input.  This when i give <input
  formControlName="phoneNo"
  validityStyle 
  [submitted]="submitted"
/>

Comment: and the directive has the `@Input() submitted` declared?

Comment: yes   @Input() submitted: boolean = false;

Comment: just figured that i had not registered the directive in the module

Comment: I can see it works but what if i want check for the condition in certain places and not want the style

Comment: "check for condition". Ok, check for condition and do what? Currently as your questions sits, this is directly tied to styling.

Comment: sorry just rephrasing, I need to check the same condition elsewhere but apply different style. Do I control that with input parameters

Comment: This does not work when applied to div elements

Comment: your question says "directive for reactive form validation not working" and I have applied my answer according to that regarding your existing code. Yes, this is not supposed to work on divs, never was meant to be, just meant to be used for applying style to invalid formfields. Sounds to me that you might not even want a directive at all? Hard to say,I only know the code you are showing currently for the scope of this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239811/discussion-between-tom-and-at82).

Comment: If you want to avoid @Input() submitted: boolean; add private formGroup: FormGroupDirective in the constructor then use (this.formGroup as FormGroupDirective)?.submitted.